# How to retrieve all routes from another project with .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

What I am looking for is something similar to `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes` which returns a RouteCollection containing all routes. Of course the previous solution only let us retrieve the routes of the current project running, not another one.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "another project"? A project in the same solution? A project in a different solution? A project on another computer? A website? Please be clear.

Comment: Sorry, the projects are inside the same solution. So there are things I can access between projects by importing classes and so on, but I can't figure out a way to access the routes of a project A from project B (inside the same solution). In the project A the routes are not listed in a single file, there are several AreaRegistration files. NB : the projects are websites

Comment: Access them at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier I couldn't come back to stackoverflow... The project A from which I want the routes is not compiled/running. Only project B where I want to retrieve routes from project A is running.